# Explain code of exercise Python turtle spiral

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, spiral

I am a beginner in programming, trying to do some simple exercises from an online course on Python. I found a solution, but I can't understand the code. Could you explain me it in some comments below? (I would appreciate it.)

```
import turtle from math 
import sin,cos,pi 

t=turtle.Turtle() 
t.speed(0)

n=50  
d=10  
r=0 
x,y = 0, 0 
cur_r = r

for i in range(n): 
    for a in range(1,360, 4): 
        r = cur_r + d*a/360.0 
        a *= pi/180.0 y = r*sin(a) 
        x = r*cos(a) 
        turtle.goto(x,y) 
        cur_r += d
```

Comment: @iamL, your edit explanation says "Formatted the code" but you *added* as many lines of code as there were originally.  And it still doesn't run as shown.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's turn this from a non-viable code fragment into a working program:

```
import turtle
from math import *

n = 1
d = 2
cur_r = 3

for i in range(n):
    for a in range(1, 360, 4):
        r = cur_r + d * a / 360.0
        a *= pi / 180.0
        x, y = r * cos(a), r * sin(a)
        turtle.goto(x, y)
        cur_r += d

turtle.mainloop()
```

Now let's explain it as best we can.  First imports:

```
import turtle  # turtle graphics for plotting

from math import *  # get trig routines sine and cosine plus pi constant
```

Next global variables:

```
n = 1  # number of revolutions around the spiral

d = 2  # growth factor (delta) for spiral radius (in 4 degrees steps)

cur_r = 3  # initial setting of current spiral radius
```

Code:

```
for i in range(n):  # for each revolution of the spiral

    for a in range(1, 360, 4):  # angle from 1 to 359 in 4 degree steps

        r = cur_r + d * a / 360.0  # new radius based on current one + delta

        a *= pi / 180.0  # convert angle from degrees to radians

        x, y = r * cos(a), r * sin(a)  # get cartesian coordinates from polar

        turtle.goto(x, y)  # draw a line from previous point to this one

        cur_r += d  # add delta to current radius before repeating process

turtle.mainloop()  # turn control over to tkinter's event handler
```

Errors:

```
for a in range(1, 360, 4):
```

Probably should have been:

```
for a in range(0, 360, 4):
```

and the '4' should probably have been an additional variable, not hard-coded.  Since we're already importing everything from the math library:

```
a *= pi / 180.0
```

could have been written:

```
a = radians(a)
```

It's not clear what this line does:

```
r = cur_r + d * a / 360.0
```

that accomplishes more than simply:

```
r = cur_r
```

as `d * a / 360.0` only ranges from `d/360` to 'd'.  Revised code:

```
import turtle
from math import cos, sin, radians

revolutions = 1
delta = 2
radius = 3
steps = 4

for i in range(revolutions):
    for angle in range(0, 360, steps):
        angle = radians(angle)
        x, y = radius * cos(angle), radius * sin(angle)
        turtle.goto(x, y)
        radius += delta

turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think math of this exercise based on ---> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral, but I don`t find all formulas for this